# Замена четырех блоков одним. Анимация

Tags: html, css, responsive

У меня есть анимация из 4 блоков текста. В комп версии все работает как надо(там 4 блока), но в адаптивной версии мне нужен только один блок текста сменяющийся на другой через определенное время. Помогите, есть идеи как это реализовать?
Вот CSS:

```
.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 8 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2.66 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.6 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.14 * 1s);
}

.div-txt {
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
  text-align: right;
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  1%,
  24% {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  20%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  8%,
  12% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
```

Вот HTML:

```
<div class="div-wrap">
  <div class="div-wrap-txt">
    <div class="div-txt" style="padding-right: 35px;">
      <img src="img/con.svg">
      <p class="label">Cont</p>
      <p style="color: #6B7684;">the shoulders, turn<br> on it and connect application <br>with/p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-txt" style="padding-right: 35px; margin-top: 50px;">
      <img src="img/cal.png">
      <p class="label">Cal</p>
      <p style="color: #6B7684;">set up calibration to help device remember your upright and slouch positions.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-wrap-txt">
    <div class="div-txt" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 25px;">
      <img src="img/tr.svg">
      <p class="label">posture</p>
      <p style="color: #6B7684;">posture anytime you want, <br>set up daily goal to improve gradually <br>your posture.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-txt" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 25px; margin-top: 50px;">
      <img src="img/an12.png">
      <p class="label">Anaasd</p>
      <p style="color: #6B7684;">track and analyze the <br>progress you’ve made from first <br>training to the last.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Анимация с блоками текстов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917462/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @UbuntuUser можете помочь с решением?